# How to show that $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n]) \cong (\mathbb{G}_m)^n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups

> How to show that $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n]) \cong (\mathbb{G}_m)^n$? Here $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the multiplicative group.

Thank you very much.

Edit: $\mathbb{G}_m = k - \{0\}$ is the multiplicative group of the ground field $k$. This isomorphism is in line 10 of Section 5 on page 10 of [this paper](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~morilac/pdag/Intro%20notes.pdf).

Edit: as pointed out by Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, we should have $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x_1^{\pm 1},x_2^{\pm 1},\ldots, x_n^{\pm 1}]) \cong (\mathbb{G}_m)^n$.

Comment: @user26857, «the multiplicative group», in this context, is a group scheme $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ with is natural structure.So it is not the multiplicative group of anything really, but the functor to which you give something and gives you its multiplicative group. LJR's edit is somewhat misguided :-)

Comment: In any case, the result LJR wants to prove is false. Even when $n=1$, $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z[x]$, the affine line, and $\mathbb G_m$ are non isomorphic schemes.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, thank you very much. Here $\mathbb{G}_m=k^*=k-\{0\}$. I think that $\text{Spec} \mathbb{Z}[x] = k^*$.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up several things. How can you identify a countable set with a possibly uncountable one? The coordinate algebra of $G_m$ is as mentioned $k[x,x^{-1}]$ when you work over the ring $k$.

Comment: @LJR I'm even more confused: I can't see any ground field $k$ in your question.

Comment: @user26857, thank you very much. I think that $\mathbb{G}_m = k - \{0\}$ for some fixed ground field $k$. But maybe my understanding is not true. I asked this question since I am trying to understand the isomorphism in line 10 of Section 5 on page 10 of [this paper](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~morilac/pdag/Intro%20notes.pdf).

Comment: The claimed isomorphism seems to be simply false. Which viewpoint of schemes are you using? Functorial or sheaf?

Comment: @user26857, thank you very much.

Comment: The formula in page 10 is just a typo: the author meant to write $x_i^{\pm1}$ instead of $x_i$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, thank you very much. Are there some proof of this fixed formula?

Comment: Of what? Of the isomorphism $(\mathbb G_m)^n\cong\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z[x_1^{\pm1},\dots,x_m^{\pm1}]$? That is almost trivial, if you know the basics of algbraic groups, really. I suggest you read up a  bit on that.

Comment: I think a source of confusion here is that you have the wrong definition of $G_m$. It is not just the multiplicative group of the group field (at least not if it is to be Spec of the given ring, which is not even an algebra over some field).

Comment: Wow the notation $\mathbb{G}_m$ is just horrible. It makes the notation look like a sequence, you're left looking around for an $m$ somewhere.

Comment: @user26857, my thoughts exactly :)

Comment: @goblin: This notation is completely standard in algebraic geometry and especially arithmetic geometry (and is used in conjunction with the notation $\mathbb G_a$ for the additive group).

Comment: @tracing, oh I accept that, it came straight out of a research article after all. Its still *aweful* though. Here's a suggestion: surely $\mathbb{G}_\times$ and $\mathbb{G}_+$ would be better. True, some might accidentally interpret this as "the underlying additive structure of this thing called $\mathbb{G}$", but that really would be better denoted $U_+ G$ or $U_{\mathbf{Ab}} G$ or whatnot.

Comment: $\mathbb G_\times$ and $\mathbb G_+$ look to me like the invertible and positive parts of this thing called $\mathbb G$.  I don't see that as being any better...